# How to impose restrictions on VECM model in R?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Good afternoon!

I want to estimate VECM in R and I have a question. Consider an example. I want to estimate a 4-variable VECM model with restrictions:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \bigtriangleup x_t \\
    \bigtriangleup y_t \\
    \bigtriangleup z_t \\
    \bigtriangleup w_t
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    -\beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3  & \beta_4 \\
    -\beta_5 & \beta_6 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    x_t \\
    y_t \\
    z_t \\
    w_t
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \varepsilon_{x_t} \\
    \varepsilon_{y_t} \\
    \varepsilon_{z_t} \\
    \varepsilon_{w_t}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So I assume, that $x_t$ is cointegrated with other variables, $y_t$ is cointegrated only with $x_t$ but $z_t$ and $w_t$ are exogenous variables (maybe their path is determined by their own past values only). So can how can I impose such restrictions on cointegrating relationships of VECM in `R`?

By the way, are the restrictions I imposed in the second question theoretically correct? It seems that second restricted cointegrated relationship (from the second row of coefficient matrix) is already contained in the first row of coefficient matrix...